# how to merge output of collection aggregator with array of xml files that are seperated by comma using xslt and mule

Tags: xml, xslt, mule

I need to merge a array of xml's into one xml file. Below is the output from `Collection Aggregator` in mule.

**Output:**

```
[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><log>
        <age>nameorder3</age>
        <name>tetsMessage3</name>
    </log>, <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><log>
        <age>nameorder2</age>
        <name>tetsMessage2</name>
    </log>, <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><log>
        <age>nameorder1</age>
        <name>tetsMessage1</name>
    </log>]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<root>
<log>
    <age>nameorder3</age>
    <name>tetsMessage3</name>
</log>
<log>
    <age>nameorder2</age>
    <name>tetsMessage2</name>
</log>
<log>
    <age>nameorder1</age>
    <name>tetsMessage1</name>
</log>
```

Comment: can you paste the flow XML here? How are you reading 4 XMLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you are using `Collection Aggregator` you will be getting arrays of xml like [xml1, xml2, ... so on as you mentioned.
So, you need to extract each payload and save into a variable and the pass those xml values of variables into your XSL file that will generate your expected result ...  You can try something as follow after the `Collection Aggregator` :-

```
<set-variable variableName="value1" value="#[message.payload[0][0].replace('&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;','')]" doc:name="Variable"/>
<set-variable variableName="value2" value="#[message.payload[0][1].replace('&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;','')]" doc:name="Variable"/>
```

Then you can set any dummy xml payload before your Xslt transformer and pass the xml payload from each variable to your xsl files:-

```
<set-payload value="#[message.payload[0][0]]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
<mulexml:xslt-transformer xsl-file="response.xsl" maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" doc:name="XSLT" mimeType="application/xml">
       <mulexml:context-property key="value1" value="#[flowVars.value1]" /> 
       <mulexml:context-property key="value2" value="#[flowVars.value2]" /> 
</mulexml:xslt-transformer>
```

Place your response.xsl file under ***src/main/resources*** folder and your xsl file can be as follows:-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

   <xsl:param name="value1" />
   <xsl:param name="value2" />

<xsl:template match="/">
 <root>
 <xsl:value-of select="$value1"/>
 <xsl:value-of select="$value2"/>

 </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So, the full code after your `Collection Aggregator` will be:-

```
 <collection-aggregator failOnTimeout="true" doc:name="Collection Aggregator"/>
<!-- <logger message="#[message.payload[0]]   #['\n']  #[message.payload[1]]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/> -->
<set-variable variableName="value1" value="#[message.payload[0][0].replace('&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;','')]" doc:name="Variable"/>
<set-variable variableName="value2" value="#[message.payload[0][1].replace('&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;','')]" doc:name="Variable"/>
<set-payload value="#[message.payload[0][0]]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
<mulexml:xslt-transformer xsl-file="response.xsl" maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" doc:name="XSLT" mimeType="application/xml">
     <mulexml:context-property key="value1" value="#[flowVars.value1]" /> 
     <mulexml:context-property key="value2" value="#[flowVars.value2]" /> 
</mulexml:xslt-transformer>
```

Please note that I have only taken 2 xml payload as example, and you need to do it for all the xml from the combined payload array.

Right now from your example there are 3 xml, so you need to store 3 xml in flow variables and design the xsl template accordingly

**UPDATE:-**
An alternative way is to use String functions after `collection-aggregator`

```
  <collection-aggregator failOnTimeout="true" doc:name="Collection Aggregator"/>
  <set-payload value="#[message.payload.toString().replaceAll(&quot;\\[&quot;, &quot;&quot;).replaceAll(&quot;\\]&quot;,&quot;&quot;) ]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
  <set-payload value="#[message.payload.replace('&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;','')]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
 <set-payload value="#[message.payload.replace('&gt;,','&gt;')]" doc:name="Copy_of_Set Payload"/>
  <set-payload value="#['&lt;root&gt;'+payload+'&lt;/root&gt;']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```

This is a combination of String functions and regex expressions

For removing comma, use

```
<set-payload value="#[message.payload.replace('&gt;,','&gt;')]" doc:name="Copy_of_Set Payload"/>
```

This will not replace any comma in the xml nodes values